# Where is my html to include shearthis script in my wordpress folder

Tags: php, wordpress, sharethis

After I used https for my domain, I need to change the protocol for my `sharethis`  code to

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js?ver=3.3.1'></script>
```

I am not using the ShareThis plugin for my wordpress site. May I asked which file in my website folder actually include this script?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to place before end of body, i.e, before `</body>` so that it don't block rendering of rest of stuff.

Generally look inside `footer.php` but can differ with different themes

Comment: There is a bunch of `wp-*.php` files in the `html` folder. Which one did include this js file? I need to change it.

Comment: Look inside  footer.php file or if you have files locally do a text in a folder search for `</body>`

Comment: I found it. It is the `header.php` in the corresponding theme

Comment: Adding it to header.php can impact performance because your page has to wait until that javascript is loaded. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup